# Как назвать кнопку types.KeyboardButton в python библиотеке 'telebot', но при отправке сообщения не отправлять этот текст, а отправить другой?

Tags: python, telebot

Я хочу назвать кнопку "Помощь", но хочу, чтобы при ее нажатии отправлялось /help. Как это реализовать?

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
help_btn = types.KeyboardButton("Помощь")
```

При нажатии на нее в чат отправляется слово помощь. А желательно чтобы после нажатия туда пошла именно команда /help.

Comment: используйте inline-клавиатуру

Comment: а для чего вам это нужно? Если вы так планируете использовать обработчик для команд, то это очень плохая реализация. Просто используйте одновременно фильтр и на команду и на текст